# How do Salesforce query using the relationships table behind the scenes?

Tags: mysql, sql, salesforce, metadata

I'm trying to figure out how Salesforce's metadata architecture works behind the scenes. There's a video they've released ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrKA3cJmoms ) where he goes through many of the important tables that drive it along (about 18m in).

I've figured out the structure for the basic representation / storage / retrieval of simple stuff, but where i'm hazy is how the relationship pivot table works. I'll be happy when:

a) I know exactly how the pivot table relates to things (RelationId column he mentions is not clear to me)
b) I can construct a query for it.

[Screenshot from the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuIaF.png)

I've not had any luck finding any resources describing it at this level in the detail I need, or managed to find any packages that emulate it that I can learn from.

Does anyone have any low-level experience with this part of Salesforce that could help?

**EDIT**: Thank you, David Reed for further details in your edit. So presumably you agree that things aren't exactly as explained?

- In the 'value' column, the GUID of the related record is stored
- This allows ease of fetching -to-one related records and, with a little bit of simple SQL switching, resolve a group of records in the reverse direction.
- I believe Salesforce don't have many-to-many relationships, as opposed to using a 'junction', so the above is still relevant

I guess now though I wonder what the point of the pivot table is at all, as there's a very simple relationship going on here now. Unless the lack of index on the value columns dictates the need for one...

Or, could it be more likely/useful if:

- The record's value column stores a GUID to the *relationship* record and not directly to the related record?
- This *relationship* record holds all necessary information required to put together a decent query and ALSO includes the GUID of the related record?

Neither option clear up the ambiguity for me, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see, query, or otherwise access the internal tables that underlie Salesforce's on-platform schema. When you build an application on the platform, you query relationships using [SOQL relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm); there are no pivot tables involved in the work you can see and do on the platform.

While some presentations and documentation discuss at some level the underlying implementation, the precise details of the SQL tables, schemas, query optimizers, and so on are not public.

As a Salesforce developer or developer who interacts with Salesforce via the API, you do not need to worry about the underlying SQL implementation used on Salesforce's servers at almost any time. The main point at which that knowledge can become helpful is when you are working with massive data volumes (multiple millions of records). The most helpful documentation for that use case is [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm#!). The underlying schema is briefly discussed under [Underlying Concepts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_concepts_multitenancy_and_metadata.htm). But bear in mind

> As a customer, you also cannot optimize the SQL underlying many application operations because it is generated by the system, not written by each tenant.

The implementation details are also subject to change.

#### Metadata Tables and Data Tables

> When an organisation declares an object’s field with a relationship type, Force.com maps the field to a Value field in MT_Data, and then uses this field to store the ObjID of a related object.

I believe the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture) you mentioned is using the identifier `ObjId` ambiguously, and here actually means what it refers to earlier in the document as `GUID` - the Salesforce Id. Another paragraph states

> The MT_Name_Denorm table is a lean data table that stores the ObjID and Name of each record in MT_Data. When an application needs to provide a list of records involved in a parent/child relationship, Force.com uses the MT_Name_Denorm table to execute a relatively simple query that retrieves the Name of each referenced record for display in the app, say, as part of a hyperlink.

This also doesn't make sense unless `ObjId` is being used to mean what is called `GUID` in the visual depiction of the table above in the document - the Salesforce Id of the record.

Comment: Hey David, just to clarify my question/source though; Salesforce don't shy away from telling people how this stuff works, at a fairly lowish level. Even to the point of showing "pseudo" tables/fields. However....
In official dev material I've read, they state "When an organisation declares an object’s field with a relationship type, Force.com maps the field to a Value field in MT_Data, and then uses this field to store the ObjID of a related object."

However this makes no mention of the related *record* ID. Just the object ID.

I'm not a Salesforce dev, just an inquisitive PHP one :)

Comment: This document: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture

refers to "Multitenant Relationships" which I quoted in my above comment.